# Translate sentence into a first order logic statement

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

I would like to know how to translate something in FOL.

I am defining a signal (but could be everything) and I would like to say that

1. it has a numeric dimension in a specific system (the numeric dimension have meaning only in that specific system, such as coordinate and WGS84)
2. it is not equal to any of its surrounding (the adjacent signal have something different in quality or quantity)
3. it is member of a set of signs call C.

but I am quite bad in logic and I am not really sure how to do it.

```
Sigx = {(D, PS) | (D, PS) ≠ (Surrounding) ∧ (x ∪ C)}
```

I tried here to say that a signal x is composed of a dimension D and a position in a system PS such that the dimension and position are different from the one of the surroundings and is a member of the set C.

I am quite sure it is not the proper way, so whatever help is very much appreciated! Specifically I would like to know: 
- how can I write it?
- if and how we can specify that D is a numeric dimension (it is a x member of the set of natural numbers? or Dx1,...,xn?)

Comment: Could be also:  signal(x) → ∀x.(hasDimension(x, N) ∧ isPartOf(x, system) ∧ different(x, surrounding) ∧ (x ∈ CT)) ?

Comment: In your original post you don't really use logic, but rather define a set which uses some (wrong) logical conditions. Your comment is almost correct. The $\forall$ should quantify the whole implication tho. (And I assume CT is just a typo and means C?)

Comment: I only saw right now the comment. sorry for the delay. Yes, you are right, I actually cut the CT part and it is now like this: ∀signal(x) → ∀x.((hasDimension(x, N) ∧ isPartOf(x, system)) ∧ different(x, surrounding) )

Answer (score 0):

The correct form in FOL is:
∀signal(x) → ∀x.((hasDimension(x, N) ∧ isPartOf(x, system)) ∧ different(x, surrounding) ∧  (x ∈ C))

Thanks to @pattuX for the helping polish everything :)